# Anisotropic Hiesenberg model

Tags: condensed-matter, spin-chains

I am reading the review article, "Quantum spin chains and Haldane gap" by I Affleck (http://iopscience.iop.org/article/10.1088/0953-8984/1/19/001/pdf). At one point of the discussion, he considers an anistropic Hisenberg model (page 3062) given by $H = J \sum (\textbf S_i.\textbf S_{i+1} - b S^z_i S^z_{i-1})$. Then he claims that for $b$ very large and negative, the spins lie in the $X-Y$ plane. I do not understand this statement because
for $|b| >>1$, the Hamiltonian reduces to an Ising model and the spin should lie entirely along $\pm z$ direction and not in the $X-Y$ plane. Only when $b = +1$, the spin will lie in the $X-Y$ plane. What am I missing here ?